# Why every Redux Middleware can call next(action), wouldn't it dispatch one action multiple times?

Tags: javascript, redux

I was reading official [tutorials](https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware#the-final-approach) about middlewares.

I am confused about this line of middleware code: `next(action)`

From my understanding, the `next` function is actually `store.dispatch`, and every Middleware will call `next(action)`, wouldn't it dispatch that action multiple times?

So here are two Middlewares:

```js
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action) // I'm talking about this line
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}

const crashReporter = store => next => action => {
  try {
    return next(action) // This line too.
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Caught an exception!', err)
    Raven.captureException(err, {
      extra: {
        action,
        state: store.getState()
      }
    })
    throw err
  }
}
```

Line 3 and 10 both call `next(action)`, plus I have the very first `store.dispatch(action)`, wouldn't that action be dispatched 3 times?

Wouldn't that break the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [applyMiddleware source code](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9c0b74192348fd10b66b44f39bf659d4125164f2/src/applyMiddleware.js#L33) you have that `dispatch` is modified as follows:

```js
const fakeStore = {
  getState: store.getState,
  dispatch: (...args) => dispatch(...args)
}
const chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(fakeStore))
dispatch = compose(...chain)(store.dispatch)
```

where [compose](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9c0b74192348fd10b66b44f39bf659d4125164f2/src/compose.js) is just function composition.

So if you called `applyMiddleware(logger, crashReporter)`, then the argument `next` of your `logger` middleware would be just `crashReporter(fakeStore)`, not `dispatch`.

In general, `next` would be the next middleware (hence the name).